# Copy/Paste file path in already open file dialog window (3rd party) with VBA

Tags: vba, dialog, sendkeys

My native language isn't English and I am relativly new to VBA, so I apologize in advance.
My problem is the following: A part of my VBA code trys to copy and paste a file path from the clipboard  that was defined in a string variable before. I do have a solution but that consists of using "Sendkeys" - not quite content with that one even if it works

Is there an alternative way to Sendkeys ? Like for example to find and activate the already open file dialog, specifically the input field within, and set the string variable directly into that field ? (I hope the attached picture makes it clearer what I imagine)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRiTw.png)

Answer (score 0):

see if following VB code, making use of Powershell, can be of any help to you..

```
Sub OpenFileUsingPowershell()
 
Dim Powershell_Command, Your_Code As Variant
Dim File_Path, File_Path_with_Spaces As String

File_Path_with_Spaces = "D:\Test Path\Test File.xlsx"    'use file path you have copied from clipboard

File_Path = Replace(File_Path_with_Spaces, " ", Chr(39) & " " & Chr(39))

Your_Code = "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms ; $FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{" & Chr(13) & _
"InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')" & Chr(13) & _
"Filter = 'SpreadSheet (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx'" & Chr(13) & _
"FileName=" & File_Path & "}" & Chr(13) & "$null = $FileBrowser.ShowDialog()"

Powershell_Command = Shell("POWERSHELL.exe " & Your_Code, 0)   'See Note below.


End Sub
```

Note : In the above code try using `Powershell_Command = Shell("POWERSHELL.exe -noexit " & Code, 1)` instead of `Powershell_Command = Shell("POWERSHELL.exe " & Your_Code, 0)` just to see what's happening !

Comment: Thank you for answering. Would this solution also work if the "open file dialog" was opened by citrix ? Meanwhile I also found out that my initial thought for an alternative does exist (by using spy++ for example). But, while it worked on "normal windows", it didn't work with Citrix related windows.

Comment: Hi, sorry I am not quite aware about Citrix environment; the code I posted is for regular Windows. However request you to drop your code in your question with comments wherever you feel there are exceptions (e.g. Citrix you mentioned), so that someone else having required know-how can help you.