# VBA pick a file from a specific location?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm attempting to put together some code in VBA where it will open a specific folder, let me choose the file then continue running my code.

Currently what I have (below) "works" in that it will open a folder but usually it starts from a generic location (Desktop) but will not go the the specific folder location to let me open the file I want.

```
Dim Filename as String

filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,  *.xl*;*.xm*")
If filename <> False Then
Workbooks.Open filename:=filename
End If
```

I've also tried something like this:

```
Dim Directory as String
Dim Filename as String

Directory = "\\page\data\NFInventory\groups\CID\Retail Setting\Lago Retail Uploads\" & strBrand & "\" & strSeason & "\" & strPrefix & "\"
Filename = Dir(Directory & "*.xl*;*.xm*")
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Directory
```

But it doesn't do anything and I think I have everything right. Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

-Deke

Comment: [Maybe helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372319/vba-folder-picker-set-where-to-start).

Comment: Pls check out my reply to this post  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63318815/copy-paste-file-path-in-already-open-file-dialog-window-3rd-party-with-vba/63333637#63333637]. You may get some breakthrough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will start an Open Dialog at the specified location:

```
Sub openBeckJFolder()

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Show
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\beckj\"
    End With
 
End Sub
```

The [Microsoft document page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog) doesn't really get into it, but `FileDialog` has several features such as the `InitialFileName` that I used here.

_

**UPDATE: To open the workbook**

Code added that allows you to highlight the workbook & click `Open`, or `double-click` on the workbook to open it.

```
Sub openBeckJFolder()

    Dim Filename As String
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\beckj\"
        
        If .Show = True Then
            Filename = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    
    Workbooks.Open (Filename)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply! this kinda works, but it isn't opening the file I selected.

Comment: that did it. Thanks all!